# cannot get data of column #id

Tags: php, odbc

I want to echo some values of a query

```
while(odbc_fetch_row($tableX)) 
{     
  for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($tableX);$i++) 
  {
    if ($i==1)
    {
      echo odbc_result($tableX,1); //echoed
      echo odbc_result($tableX,2); //echoed
      echo odbc_result($tableX,21); //echoed
      echo odbc_result($tableX,22); //echoed
      var_dump(odbc_result($tableX,22)); //returns values
    }
    else if($i==2)
    {
      echo odbc_result($tableX,$i).'++';
      var_dump(odbc_result($tableX,22)); //returns bool(false) and empty rows     
    }  
    else if($i==3)
    {
      echo odbc_result($tableX,$i).'+';   
    } 
    else
    {
      echo odbc_result($tableX,$i); //($tableX,1) ($tableX,2) ($tableX,3) echoed ($tableX,21) ($tableX,22) not echoed
    }
  }
}
```

As I indicated in the comments, some of the odbc_result's raises an error:

> cannot get data of column #21
> cannot get data of column #22

I (am not sure but) think the issue is:

> An error occurs if a column number parameter for a field is less than
> one or exceeds the number of columns (or fields) in the current
> record. Similarly, an error occurs if a field with a name that is not
> one of the fieldnames of the table(s) that is(are) being queried.

Yet, I couldn't see the reason.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Else works if I delete the echoes under `if ($i==1)`
Both 21 & 22's data type is NCLOB

Comment: What value does `odbc_num_fields($tableX)` return?

Comment: it returns 27 @ADyson

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying that when you write `odbc_result($tableX,22)` specifically it outputs the value, but if you write `odbc_result($tableX,$i)` it does not, even when $i has the value 22? Are you completely sure about that? Because it does not make any sense

Comment: @ADyson right!? it is frustrating. I typed ``echo odbc_result($tableX,22);`` under else as well, still raises an error.

Comment: @wittream it may exist, but does it have a value in all the rows in the results? Also where do these "cannot get data..." messages come from exactly? Are they PHP warnings, or notices, or what? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-result.php only mentions that it returns `false` if there's an error, or `null` if the column is empty. (If you use `var_dump` instead of `echo` for testing this, temporarily, you'll be able to see exactly what output it returns in these cases - `false` and `null` isn't ordinarily visible when using `echo`, for example)

Comment: @ADyson you're right, value of column 22 doesnt exist for every row (some of them are null), but it doesn't echo for the ones that has a value.  I checked  again and it is a warning ``Warning: odbc_result(): Cannot get data of column #21  odbc_result(): Cannot get data of column #22`` for the line under ``else``.``var_dump`` results bool(false) for 21 and 22 for some rows (probably the ones that has null value) and empty for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by converting NCLOBs `(odbc_result($tableX,21) and odbc_result($tableX,22))` to nvarchar

```
CAST(BINTOSTR(CAST("COLUMNNAME" AS binary)) as nvarchar)
```